# How can I read an ISO-9660 (or any other FS) with file names in non-UTF (CP866 in my case) codepage?

Tags: linux, console, mount, codepages, cp866

Actually the question is in the topic.
I've got an old CD with ISO-9660/Juliet FS with filenames in CP866 (Neuro Burning ROM did a lot crazy things like that back in times). The disc mounts and works under Windows perfectly.
I know it is CP866 because "*ls | iconv -f CP866*" shows correct file names.

How can I mount it with correct file names under a **modern** Ubuntu?
The thing is that the ancient solution:

> mount -o ro,norock,codepage=866 /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom

Doesn't work anymore:

> wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0, missing
> codepage or helper program, or other error.

The "iocharset" mount options does nothing and doesn't affect visible file names.

Did Linux lose the ability to work with old file systems?

Comment: The standard for CD is 8.3 ASCII filenames.  Linux automatically supports the Joliet extension which allows Unicode filenames. codepage is only supported for FAT or VFAT filesystems. There is no corresponding standard for ISO-9660.

Comment: Yeah, I know that it's against the current ISO9660 standard, but a lot of CDs were made with non-unicode file name encoding. I'd even say the majority of CDs that have been written 7 and more years ago.  As I understand it was a "Romeo" - an ISO-9660 extension and Juliet's ancestor. And Linux supported those CDs perfectly (by specifying custom code page for them). Seems that this capability was lost from 2 to 5 years ago. That's so unusual for the Linux-world to lose functionality...